# How to use MYSQL WHERE on a field with no value at all

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

In a script, I am trying to get all records where 2010Combination.cellGroom has no value.

This is the SQL I am using ...

```
SELECT person.*, horse.*, 2010Combination.*, country.* , country.* 
FROM FEIPerson AS person JOIN 2010Combination ON person.fei_id = 2010Combination.personFEIid 
JOIN FEIHorse horse ON horse.fei_id = 2010Combination.horseFEIid 
JOIN country ON country.ISO_A3 = person.competing_for_country 
WHERE 2010Combination.cellGroom = ''
ORDER BY person.competing_for_country, ASC
```

Testing in PHPMYADMIN results with no records but there are 100+.

Whats wrong here?

Comment: Hint:  `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: hi Gordon, It responds with #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ASC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `ORDER BY` sorts in `ASC` order so you do not need `ASC` in `ORDER BY`. Although there is a typo in `ORDER BY` which i have removed. You need to use `IS NOT NULL` in query to avoid `NULL` records.

```
SELECT person.*, horse.*, 2010Combination.*, country.* , country.* 
FROM FEIPerson AS person 
JOIN 2010Combination ON person.fei_id = 2010Combination.personFEIid 
JOIN FEIHorse horse ON horse.fei_id = 2010Combination.horseFEIid 
JOIN country ON country.ISO_A3 = person.competing_for_country 
WHERE 2010Combination.cellGroom IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY person.competing_for_country
```

Comment: What was the typo in would like to know

Comment: comma in `ORDER BY person.competing_for_country, ASC`

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between a column value being empty (`NULL`) or containing an empty string (`''`).

Your values are probably `NULL` and you can filter those with the `is` operator which is *NULL-safe*. Most other operators return *unknown* when compared with NULL which is obviously not *true*.

```
WHERE 2010Combination.cellGroom IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: it now returns:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ASC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 6

Comment: Remove the comma before `asc`

Comment: SELECT person.*, horse.*, 2010Combination.*, country.* , country.* FROM FEIPerson AS person 
JOIN 2010Combination ON person.FEI_id = 2010Combination.personFEIid 
JOIN FEIHorse horse ON horse.FEI_id = 2010Combination.horseFEIid 
JOIN country ON country.ISO_A3 = person.competing_for_country 
WHERE 2010Combination.cellGroom IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY person.competing_for_country , 2010Combination.stableNumber

The above SQL command gives the same result as where the WHERE line not present